# Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "active". Expected Boolean, got String with value "true"

Tags: laravel, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I try to set active prop on navbar in bootstrap vue if the current url have name of the menu in it.

```
 <b-navbar-nav>
          <b-nav-item :href="menu.link"
           v-for="menu in menus" 
           :key="menu.name" :active="urlActive.indexOf(menu.name)>0 ? true : false"
          >
          {{trans.get('back.'+menu.name)}}
          </b-nav-item>
</b-navbar-nav>
```

if my current url is /dashboard or /company it doesnt show any warning but if i go to create or edit

i.g /company/create or /company/edit it show the warning.
Any help is appricaite

Comment: The code you provided looks correct, the value used in `active` is a boolean. The problem might come from another place…

Comment: what is do you mean by another place?

Comment: Somewhere else in the code base where you also have an `active` prop?

Comment: no I already search the whole project but doesn't seem to find it anywhere...